# Como reproducir video automáticamente después de cerrar ventana modal

Tags: javascript, php, html-video

Estoy en la tarea de reproducir un video automáticamente después de cerrar una ventana modal, tengo un pequeño desarrollo donde tengo embebido un video y la ventana modal en una función de PHP, el cual es el siguiente:

```
public function vistaTest(){
        echo 
        '<div class="row col-md-12">

        <div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:Lettera Text Std; font-size: 12px; display: block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title Message</h4>
                    </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                        <h5>Message Test</h5>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button name="Acepta" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
                </div>


            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
            <div id="siteVideo">
                
                    
         <video id="videoTest" width="640" height="480" controls controlsList="nodownload">
            <source src="VIDEOTEST.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          </video>
   
            </div>
         </div>';            
    }
```

Adicional cuento con un evento para mostrar el mensaje en la ventana modal y cerrarla en dar click en aceptar, el cual es el siguiente:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    $('#largeModal').modal({ show: false, 
                             backdrop: 'static', 
                             keyboard: false});
    $('#largeModal').modal('show');
  });
```

Lo que deseo es que al dar click en el boton aceptar se reproduzca el vídeo.

Comment: Detecta cuando se [cierre la ventana modal](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/jquery+detect+modal+close) y ahí inicia la [reproducción del video](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-play-pause-video-using-jquery/)

Comment: @Triby Algún ejemplo en base a mi desarrollo el cual me puedas aportar como respuesta para darle validez ?

Comment: ¿Revisaste los enlaces? Es muy sencillo, inténtalo y, si tienes problemas, entonces edita la pregunta con lo que intentaste para poder tratar de ayudarte.